# How to call an override method from a class to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, overriding

I had a simple doubt , can I use override methods from a class in android..I used the code below code in my activity

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
      if (hasFocus) {

    frameAnimation.start();
    } else {

    frameAnimation.stop();
      }
}
```

my question is can this method define in another class and call in my activity in 2 or 3 line code ?? please help me ,thanks in advance :)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Please clarify.

Comment: i want declare above method in a separate class and call it in my activity, but how to override it when I do so ??

Comment: That didn't help. Do you mean you want to start the animation in the Activity from another class?

Comment: yes....how to do this??

Comment: The simplest way would be to create a public method in the Activity, and call that. You need to be careful implementing this, though, as you can easily cause leaks. It really depends on what your other class is, and its relation to the Activity.